# How to make a bitmap font having only a PNG file?

Tags: fonts

Is there a way to "convert" an existing PNG file with the characters' images into a bitmap font? Basically, I want to create a FNT file using an image like this...
[image: font image]
<sub>(source: [opengameart.org](http://opengameart.org/sites/default/files/font.png))</sub>

...without the access to a TTF file of the image's characters or any other typical font formats.

Answer (score 3):

The characters in such a monospace font are ordered in increasing ASCII codepoint row-major order.

This means that you can derive the cell offset by simple arithmetic. Given the codepoint `base` of the top left character, the cell index `col,row` of a codepoint `ch` is:

```
col= (ch-base) % columns
row= (ch-base) / columns
```

You can then compute X and Y of the rectangle by multiplying the cell index by the width/height of a cell.

Given the computed extents of each character, you can then emit a FNT file based on the [FNT specification](https://web.archive.org/web/20141214110828/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/65123/en-us), or try to find a FNT generator that you can provide with input regions and a bitmap.

Comment: Good to know, I wasn't aware that the characters' order is actually according to ASCII. Still, sadly, it's not enough to easily create a bitmap font out of it - is there a tool that could process such image or do I have to write an application which could generate a FNT file according to the given sheet? Guess I'll probably have to study the FNT file structure.